# Reload a page over and over from console

Tags: javascript, loops, reload

I've tried using my Browser's console in order to reload the page over and over every 5 seconds, but it's not working at all.

I have used the code below, however, it reloads the page one time but the loop doesn't continue for some reason.

```
    setTimeout(function()
{
       window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: 1. You probably want to use `setInterval` (and not `setTimeout` - which gets called only once). 2. You **can't do this** - after the first time the page was reloaded - the old script is not running anymore (and so even if you change your code to `setInterval` - it will stop.

Comment: There are extensions for most browsers that will do this for you.  Or if the code is your own, add the script to your page (or use the meta refresh tag)